# Pegar usuário logado

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, autenticação

Em meu projeto tenho um módulo de autenticação e *logout*. Mas eu queria que quando o usuário logasse eu pegasse o *id* dele para que eu mostrasse as informações referentes ao *login* dele. Tipo uma *view* de detalhes mesmo. Mas que o usuário que logasse, tivesse um *link* e nesse *link* já tivesse o *id* dele pra que quando ele clicasse na página de detalhes mostrasse as informações e caso queira editar também seja possível pegando esse *id*.

A saber, estou usando autenticação customizada. Então como posso fazer isso ?

Vou colocar minhas *actions* de *login* e *logout*:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(String Login, String Senha)
    {
        //verificando login pelo usuario do banco de dados ...
        Usuario login = db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.Login == Login && x.Senha == Senha).FirstOrDefault();
        if (login != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login, false);
            Session.Add(".PermissionCookie", login.Perfil);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //pagina padrao para todos os usuarios...
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    public ActionResult Sair()
    {

        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Remove(".PermissionCookie");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[A resposta do @DiegoZanardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40887/2999) se aproxima muito do pedido em pergunta. Apenas vou acrescentar algumas informações:

### `SetAuthCookie`

Acho errado colocar um campo de Id num *Cookie* que aceita `String`, então mudaria pra isso:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Login.toString(), false);
```

### *Controller*, não *View*

```
public ActionResult Detalhes()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var userName = User.Identity.Name;
        var usuario = db.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Login == userName);

        if (usuario != null)
            return View(usuario);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

## *View*

```
@model Usuario

<p>Login: @usuario.Login</p>
<p>Data de Nascimento: @usuario.DataNascimento</p>
@* Coloque aqui mais detalhes da sua View *@
```

Comment: Cigano como que eu posso colocar esse id do usuário pra um link pra que eu possa redirecionar o usuário pra uma página de detalhes e para editar o dados ? Tipo o *Manager* do Identity. Esse link ficaria numa *partial* que seria renderizada na *_Layout*. Deixando dessa forma que ta ai que você fez, aparecendo o nome do usuário.

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Como você quer o formato do link? Isso influencia em como o *Controller* chamado será construído.

Comment: Tipo, queria que no link mostrasse o nome do usuário e ao clicar ele fosse redirecionado pra uma página que tenha os detalhes relacionados a ele e nessa página tenha um link pra edição dos dados dele também.

Comment: A minha resposta e a resposta do @DiegoZanardo já fazem isso. O que estaria faltando nelas?

Comment: Mas o que acontece é que não vem o *Id* do usuário dessa forma que você me passou... Como que eu faria ?

Comment: Você pode pegar o Id do usuário internamente. Não tem qualquer motivo pra ele vir na URL ou qualquer outro dispositivo.

Comment: Como que eu faria isso então ? Porque eu queria que no link ele reconhecesse o id do usuario pra que ele pudesse alterar seus dados e ver os detalhes tambem

Comment: O usuário é seu ou é de outra pessoa?

Comment: O usuário que ta logado na aplicação

Comment: Como eu te falei, e as respostas mostram bem, **não precisa**. Você só precisa fazer uso do contexto e trazer a identificação do usuário internamente, usando `User.Identity.Name`.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro lugar, o `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` recebe uma `String` e um `Boolean`, `SetAuthCookie(String, Boolean)`. Não podendo ser `SetAuthCookie(Usuario, Boolean)`, como está fazendo.

Logo ficaria assim, supondo que a classe `Login` tenha `ID`:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.ID.toString(), false);
```

Então sua `View` de detalhes seria:

```
public ActionResult Detalhes()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        int ID = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        Usuario usuario = db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(usuario);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: esse *Current* não é reconhecido, dá erro... Tem alguma notação que se usa, ou algum *using* ? Porque ele não é reconhecido.

Comment: E como que faço pra chamar esse action a partir do *_Layout* ? Pra que quando clicar seja redirecionado pros detalhes referentes aquele *id* que ta logado ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago @DiegoZanardo Não precisa usar `HttpContext.Current.User`. Apenas `User` o `Controller` já reconhece.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez poderia colocar em resposta então ? de forma que eu consiga colocar no link o id e e tal ?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, usando o método **.GetUserId()**

Para o método estar disponível diretamente, você precisa usar:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

Após isso você poderá obter o id do usuário logado:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Comment: Esse método retorna um System.Guid